# User Messaging Platform SDK : How to determine whether we are allowed to display Personalized Ads, or Non-personalized ads?

Tags: android, admob, user-messaging-platform

All the while, we are using deprecated [Google Mobile Ads Consent SDK](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android)

Its `ConsentStatus` allow us to know, whether we should display **Personalized Ads**, or **Non-personalized ads**.

Please refer to the source code : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android/blob/main/consent-library/src/main/java/com/google/ads/consent/ConsentStatus.java

```
public enum ConsentStatus {
    @SerializedName("unknown")
    UNKNOWN,
    @SerializedName("non_personalized")
    NON_PERSONALIZED,
    @SerializedName("personalized")
    PERSONALIZED,
}
```

Google highly recommend us to migrate over [User Messaging Platform SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy)

However, we notice that there is no way to know, whether we are allowed to display **Personalized Ads**, or **Non-personalized ads**. The new `ConsentStatus` look as following.

```
public @interface ConsentStatus {
    int UNKNOWN = 0;
    int NOT_REQUIRED = 1;
    int REQUIRED = 2;
    int OBTAINED = 3;
}
```

[image]

---

May I know, if we are applying **User Messaging Platform SDK**, what kind of logic we should use, to determine whether we are allowed to display **Personalized Ads**, or **Non-personalized ads**?